# Offset to two dynamic ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I have two dynamic ranges that I'll call rng1 and rng2.  I have a for each/next loop going through rng1 (example: A2,A3,A4,A5, etc...)  I also need to get the same row value from rng2 (example: T2,T3,T4,T5, etc), but the range isn't always the same so a standard offset won't work (that I know of).

Any ideas?

How I set up the range (excludes the header and finds the last row)

```
lastrowTN = ws.Cells(65536, phcell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
Set rngtocopyTN = ws.Range(phcell.Offset(1, 0).Address, Cells(lastrowTN, phcell.Column))
```

Comment: The ranges are created and based on the header. I'll add an example in my post.

Comment: This doesn't make sense yet, but if you elaborate, I think the solution should be fairly straightforward...

Comment: you need to define any relation between these two ranges. between column A and T there is just .Offset(0,19) but you said it's not working. so, find the rule to get help...

Comment: I am doing a .find on the column headings to find the right column.  I apologize for not adding that.  So, based on the .find... I identify the column and do my loop on that column.  I do another .find to identify the other column and set that range.  I just cant figure out how to relate the two ranges and offsets.

Comment: i"m not sure how to write that out pnuts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say without context, but I think the Intersect method can accomplish what you're looking for.  It will find an intersection regardless of how close or far away the two ranges are.  So using your example:

[EDIT]: I realized that you could alternatively use the Cells method (code has been updated to show that as well)

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim LoopCell As Range

    Set rng1 = Range("A2:A5")
    Set rng2 = Range("T2:T5")

    For Each LoopCell In rng1.Cells
        MsgBox Intersect(LoopCell.EntireRow, rng2.EntireColumn).Address
        MsgBox Cells(LoopCell.Row, rng2.Column).Address
    Next LoopCell

End Sub
```

Note that rng1 and rng2 could be in any column and it would still find them (assuming of course that they are both on the same sheet).

Comment: This is what I needed:  {strYes = Cells(ir.Row, rngtocopyTN.Column).Value}  and you got me there, thank you!

Comment: I was trying to avoid another loop and now i can send both cell values through a function with just one loop.